# Can I have a route similar to a physical folder and not get HTTP 403.14 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an asp.net mvc 5 application and I'm working with areas, so my project has an "Areas" folder in the root. I want to have a route like: "~/areas", but if I try to access that route I get:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>
> The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Is there a way I can acomplish that? I do need the ~/areas route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this problem by rewriting the URL to use a route that is not blocked. Note that you will need to have the IIS rewrite module installed on your web server in order to use this. Just add this to your web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewrite Area" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^areas/?$"/>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="Areas/Index" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The above code rewrites `/Areas` to go to `/Areas/Index`. Then just use an Areas controller to return your view from the Index method like you normally would.

```
public class AreasController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Areas/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```